# How to evaluate open intervals in ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, intersection

I want to `ContourPlot` an expression over an interval that excludes some points. Since i dont know how to do it I wrote

```
ContourPlot[{((1 - Tanh[X])/(1 + Tanh[X]))^-k == (k + Tanh[X])/(k - Tanh[X]),((1 - Tanh[X])/(1 + Tanh[X]))^-k == -((k + Tanh[X])/(k - Tanh[X]))}, {X, -0.1, 5}, {k, -Sqrt[(3/2)], Sqrt[3/2]},PlotRange -> {{0, 5},Full}, FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\),\(\\[Phi]\)] L\), SqrtBox[\(2\)]]\)", "k"},ContourStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotLegends -> {"+sign", "-sign"}]
```

and obtained

[image]

But I want to plot for $0<k<1\cup 1<k\leq\sqrt{3/2}$ and $-\sqrt{3/2}\leq k<-1\cup -1<k<0$.

So, what I expect is the exclusion of the horizontal lines corresponding to $k=(-1,0,1)$.

Comment: Use the option "Exclusions"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Exclusions` option:

```
ContourPlot[{
   ((1-Tanh[X])/(1+Tanh[X]))^-k==(k+Tanh[X])/(k-Tanh[X]),
   ((1-Tanh[X])/(1+Tanh[X]))^-k==-((k+Tanh[X])/(k-Tanh[X]))},
  {X,-0.1,5},{k,-Sqrt[(3/2)],Sqrt[3/2]},
  PlotRange->{{0,5},Full},
  FrameLabel->{"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\),\(\\[Phi]\)] L\), SqrtBox[\(2\)]]\)","k"},ContourStyle->{Red,Blue},PlotLegends->{"+sign","-sign"},
  Exclusions->{k==0,k==1,k==-1,k==Tanh[X]}]
```

[image]

Note that I also had to exclude `k==Tanh[X]`.